# Display Pretty Code in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm looking for something I can use within django to display preformatted code.  Ideally this would include out-of-the-box syntax highlighting for various programming languages, although just starting with something that displayed html and xml well would be a good starting point.

Does something like this exist?

Basically I am looking for something like the widget dpaste (and also stack overflow) use to display code.

e.g. http://dpaste.com/hold/102141/

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<painting>
  <img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
  <caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
  <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
</painting>
```

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432439/display-django-code-from-a-django-template), but mine is not about the mechanics of escaping the code, it's about the UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Pygments](http://pygments.org) to do the syntax highlighting and get HTML to display.

Example code :

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

highlighted = highlight('# Some Python code', PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter())
```

Also see the [official documentation](http://pygments.org/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

I have found SyntaxHighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com) to work well within the Django part of my site.